# Como verificar query com retorno vazio?

Tags: sql

Tenho uma consulta com muitas colunas e quando retornar vazio quero que mostre 1. Contudo, não consigo fazer a verificação devido as muitas colunas e o `GROUP BY`.

Um exemplo simples segue abaixo :

```
SELECT ISNULL(
    (SELECT SUM(amount), p.staff_id from payment p
INNER JOIN staff s on s.staff_id=p.staff_id
GROUP BY p.staff_id),1)
```

Contudo recebo o seguinte erro :

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Como posso verificar se uma consulta é nula e atribuir um valor para ela quando tem múltiplas colunas?

Comment: o IS NULL se utiliza depois da pesquisa, seria algo desse gênero, SELECT * FROM table where NOME IS NULL, o jeito que foi utilizado pode estar causando esse erro

Comment: pode ser utilizado desta maneira mas nao acho que aceita SUM ou no caso so usei isnull ate hj com um campo no subselect

Comment: `IFNULL(...)`, `NOT ISNULL(...)`, ou `IF(campo != null, true, false) as valor`

Comment: O SUM nunca retornara null, é uma soma, vc pode fazer `SUM(campo) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Olha dei uma lida na documentação e realmente o `ISNULL` espera que a `subquery` tenha apenas um campo no no select.

no caso funcionaria
assim

```
SELECT ISNULL(
    (SELECT p.staff_id from payment p
INNER JOIN staff s on s.staff_id=p.staff_id
GROUP BY p.staff_id),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Como posso verificar se uma consulta é nula e atribuir um valor para
> ela quando tem múltiplas colunas?

**Você pode verificar múltiplas colunas usando o `CASE WHEN` conforme exemplo a seguir.**

Consideremos que o **resultado** da consulta que envolve o `group by` seja:

| produto | valor | estoque |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pneu | 150.25 | 10 |
| Filtro de AR | NULL | 5 |
| Bateria | NULL | NULL |

Conforme teste realizado no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/56f78/2802), ao executando a consulta com base no resultado acima, teríamos:

```
select *, 
       case when (valor is NULL) or (Produto is NULL) or (estoque is NULL) then 1 else 0 end as Algum_campo_eh_nulo,
       case when (valor is NULL) and (estoque is NULL)  then 1 else 0 end as Valor_e_Estoque_sao_nulos
  from 
        (
            Select 'Bateria' as produto, NULL as valor,  NULL as estoque
            union
            Select 'Pneu' as produto, 150.25 as valor, 10 as estoque
            union
            Select  'Filtro de AR' as produto, NULL as valor, 5 as estoque
        ) as x
```

**A consulta está verificando:**

1. Se algum dos campos é nulo por meio do `CASE WHEN` em conjunto com o `OR` gerando a coluna  `algum_campo_eh_nulo`;
2. Se `valor` E `estoque` são nulos por meio do `CASE WHEN` em conjunto com o `AND` gerando a coluna `Valor_e_Estoque_sao_nulos`;

**O Resultado:**

| produto | valor | estoque | algum_campo_eh_nulo | valor_e_estoque_sao_nulos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pneu | 150.25 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| Filtro de AR | NULL | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| Bateria | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 |